# this keyword and static

Tags: java, static, this, super

I knew that we can not use `this` keyword in a `static` method, But I got confused why we can not use `this` inside `static blocks` or`static methods`. Even the same case with `super()`. Could anyone shed light on this?

Thanks

Comment: `static` blocks are executet just before one of the `class`s constructors is called. so there is no object that could be referenced by `this`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` and `super` refer to the current instance and the parent instance respectively.

Within any `static` context, whether it is a `static block` or a `static method`, there is no instance to refer to, and therefore the keywords are not permitted.

`super()` is a call to the parent instance's no-arg constructor, and is only permitted as the first statement in a constructor, which disqualifies it from appearing in any static context.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)

> Within an instance method or a constructor, this is a reference to the
>   current object — the object whose method or constructor is being
>   called. You can refer to any member of the current object from within
>   an instance method or a constructor by using this.

But the static methods are related to the Class not to the object. in static methods you dont have any instance.

Answer (score 0):

Static methods and blocks are, by definition, linked to the class and not any instance of this class.

As `this` refers to the current object instance, it is perfectly normal that you cannot use it in any static initialization block or method.

Answer (score 0):

Because this points to an instance of the class, in the static method/block you don't have an instance.

Answer (score 0):

according to [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)

> Within an instance method or a constructor, `this` is a reference to the
>   current object — the object whose method or constructor is being
>   called.

So, in a static class you have NO instance variables-objects created. That's why you cannot use the `this` keyword

Answer (score 0):

Static blocks can be used to initialize static variables for example.

Static merthods are not working within an instance scope either.

Both are related to only the class and have nothing to do with an instance of that class in any way.

Answer (score 0):

To answer this we should consider what static means - it means that this bit is put in a 'static' place in memory, it exists only once.

So every class has static bits and non-static bits. The static bits exist once and the non-static bits can exist many times (i.e. lots of different instances). The word 'this' can then be thought of as shorthand for '*this* version of the non-static bits'.

In a static context we have no version of the non-static bits to refer to (or to be more precise we don't know which version we should refer to!) so we have no *this*. The same argument can be made for super.